# How to close connection to sse flux with javascript-client?

Tags: javascript, java, spring, server-sent-events, reactor

I build a server-send-event endpoint with spring webflux. My javascript app subscribes to that endpoint and receives the published events correctly. BUT when call 
 `EventSource.close()` it seems the publisher is not informed that the client closed the connection.

Hence, the publisher is still thinking that there is a subscription, and publishes events to that.

The event stream is potentially never ending, so I never get a complete signal on the publisher side, which means the client has to close the connection.

I think that this happens because the close() call can't reach the underlying flux.

Do you have any solution or workaround for this problem?

```java
@GetMapping(value = INSTANCE_UPDATE_ENDPOINT + "/{dealId}", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
public Flux<ServerSentEvent<InstanceUpdatedQuery>> getInstanceUpdateEventStreamForDeal(@PathVariable final String dealId) {

       return this.instanceUpdatedApplicationEventFlux
               .filter(instanceUpdatedEvent -> instanceUpdatedEvent.getDealId().equals(dealId))
               .map(instanceUpdatedEvent -> ServerSentEvent.<InstanceUpdatedQuery>builder()
                       .id(instanceUpdatedEvent.getId())
                       .retry(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
                       .data(new InstanceUpdatedQuery(instanceUpdatedEvent))
                       .build())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a handler to catch the doOnNext(Signal) and then detect the close signal and respond to it